# Mysqli bind param issue

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to insert data into a table. Table structure is

```
Field                   Type        Null    Key     Default     Extra
id_registro             bigint(20)  NO      PRIMARY             Auto_Increment
id_participante         int(11)     NO          
idf_votante             varchar(25) NO          
periodo                 int(8)      NO          
estado                  char(1)     NO              P   
registrado              timestamp   NO              CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

My php code is:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
include "lib/database.config.php"; //database config
        $mysqli = new mysqli($db['host'], $db['user'], $db['password'], $db['database']);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }
        $sqlAgregarVoto = "INSERT INTO ws_deta_votaciones (`id_participante`, `idf_votante`, `periodo`, `estado`) VALUES(?,?,?,?);";
        $valorPeriodo = 20120101;
        $valorEstado = 'P';
        $a = 1;
        $b= 89;
        $c = 20120101;
        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sqlAgregarVoto) ){
            //$stmt->bind_param( 'iiis',$_REQUEST['idp'],$_REQUEST['idvf'],$valorPeriodo,$valorEstado)
            $stmt->bind_param( 'iiis',$a,$b,$c,$valorEstado)
            $stmt->execute();               
            } else {
                throw new Exception($stmt->error);
                    }

?>
```

The code fails, there's some 500 internal error.

Code fails when bind_params.

Comment: Look at your server logs - that'll pinpoint the problem.

Comment: I don't have access to the logs.

Comment: On a side note - why are you using an integer for what is clearly a date value? This will come back to bite you.

Comment: The built-in error-reporting is the way to get to the problem. Either get access to the logs, or turn on some error reporting in your script. 'Some 500 internal error' won't help anyone to help you.

Comment: @MikeW the customer gave me the sql for the database. I'm not able to change it.
//Is it correct the bind_param value for integer and strings?

Comment: You're using bind_param twice, once with fixed values (`$a`, `$b`), and once with values from the REQUEST. Shouldn't you be using just one of those?

Comment: @andrewi the first bind param is commented in my code. sorry

Comment: @chepe263 - you're missing a semi-colon at the end of the bind_param line, too.

Comment: @andrewsi i think you hit the spot.

Answer (score 0):

Picking out the following choice statements

```
idf_votante             varchar(25) NO          

$sqlAgregarVoto = "INSERT INTO ws_deta_votaciones (`id_participante`, `idf_votante`, `periodo`, `estado`) VALUES(?,?,?,?);";

$b= 89;

$stmt->bind_param( 'iiis',$a,$b,$c,$valorEstado)
```

it looks like you're trying to insert an integer into idf_votante, which is defined as a varchar(25).